# ORA-00928 selecting from view over DB link, but works locally

Tags: oracle, view, oracle9i, dblink, subquery-factoring

I have a view with a query of the following form which works perfectly when I query it on the local server from any schema:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT  /*+ materialize */ ...  FROM ( SELECT ... FROM table@link)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM ( SELECT /*+ materialize */ FROM table@link )
)
SELECT ... FROM (
    SELECT ... FROM (
        SELECT ... FROM (
            SELECT ... FROM (
                SELECT ... FROM 
            )
        ) foo

        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT /*+ USE_MERGE(hle dates) */ ... FROM
        )  bar ON conditions
    )
)
UNION  ALL
SELECT ... FROM (
    SELECT ... FROM (
        SELECT ... FROM (
            SELECT ... FROM (
                SELECT ... FROM 
            )
        ) foo

        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT /*+ USE_MERGE(hle dates) */ ... FROM
        )  bar ON conditions
    )
)
```

When I run the query from any remote db link on any other server, e.g. `SELECT * from someschema.my_view@db_link`, I get:

```
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
ORA-02063: preceding line from PLLDB
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 9
```

Oracle thinks line 2 is a problem. Here are the first five actual lines:

```
WITH dates AS (
    -- Get days
    SELECT /*+ materialize */
        row_number() OVER (ORDER BY begin_period DESC) rn,
        'D' AS interval_type,
```

All other views work perfectly over the DB link (once edited to work around any related Oracle bugs).

Why does this view work perfectly locally but not over a db link?

Comment: Look like a Bug with oracle9i(BUG 768478). Please read [here](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?43937-Error-ORA-00928-when-querying-view-through-dblink)

Comment: @OracleUser: Looks like you are right. Add as an answer and I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: I did some some painting work and pasted here! Thanks!

Comment: in the patch list [here](http://www.eygle.com/Notes/9208_buglist.htm) I dont see it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Referring** from [Here](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?43937-Error-ORA-00928-when-querying-view-through-dblink)

`BUG 768478` The message "`ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword`" can occur when Oracle cost-based optimization attempts to rewrite a query that contains a set operator (e.g. UNION, `MINUS`, or `INTERSECT`) with a materialized view.

There are three workarounds:
 1. Disable query rewrite with an "`ALTER {SESSION|SYSTEM} DISABLE QUERY REWRITE`" statement.
 2. Use a `NOREWRITE` hint with all `SELECT` statements referenced by the set operator.
 3. Use a `REWRITE(mv)` hint with all `SELECT` statements in the set operator to tell the optimizer to explicitly use a *materialized* view.

`Scalar expressions` referencing SQL factoring elements ( `WITH` ... `AS` ) are not fully supported within view's subqueries. Acessing it locally work fine but remote access via `dblinks` errors out every time.